# display blob in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting "Image corrupt or truncated" error when trying to display BLOB image in a JSP page. I am using servlet to query the image and response back.

in JSP:

```
<img src="myservlet?id=5" />
```

In servlet:

```
   Blob binImage = img.getBinImage();
                            byte[] imgData = null;
                            imgData = binImage.getBytes(1, (int)binImage.length());
                            response.setContentType(img.getContentType());
                            response.setContentLength((int)binImage.length());
                            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + img.getImageName() + "\"");
                            OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream(); 
                            o.write(imgData);
                            o.flush();
                            o.close();
```

Comment: Setting the `Content-Length` header might help.

Comment: already set, still the same :(

Comment: Whats that `Content-Disposition` header doing in there? You should remove that.

Answer (score 0):

First, Base64 encode your image (blob) then you can directly use it within your `<img>` tag.

See this [link](http://www.webdesignerforum.co.uk/topic/25240-how-to-put-image-binary-data-into-html/#entry169989) (is PHP, but you will get the idea)

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg; base64, + xmlhttp.responseText + " />
```